# hashref check using if condition returns null

Tags: perl, hashref

Been using perl for a while but quite often encounter this, Say, $results is a hashref and code is like below:

```
$results->{'Key_1'} = 'Valid_string';
if ( $results->{'Key_1'} ) {  ---> this doesn't return true
   Code to do something .....
}
```

If my question is clear, Can anyone explain, why this happens?

Comment: It should test as true, `'Valid_string'` is a defined, multi-character string which does not solely consist of the character `'0'`. That's a true value. Either you wiped it out, or you misspelled something--*or* you have overridden your literal string to create an object and have created something that has bad stringifying code, or no failover and unexpected Boolean coercion. Then again, perhaps `$results` is a Tie, and you don't have good fetch code behind it. {breath} But if `$results` is simply a *hashref*, and the other two are just strings--it should always test true--if still set.

Comment: Your code should work as expected as-is. This is either not the full code, or the code inside the if-statement is ambiguous to appear as a false negative.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I guess is that `$results` is not a *HASH reference* or your "valid string" is in fact an integer : `0`

You can test it with :

```
print ref $results;
```

It should return

> HASH(0x.......)

if not, there's a problem.

---

Better test like this to avoid any surprise :

```
if (exists($results->{'Key_1'})) {
    # ...
}
```

See [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html)

And [`perldoc -f exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) :

> exists EXPR
>
> Given an expression that specifies an element of a hash, returns true if the specified element in the hash has ever been initialized, even if the corresponding value is undefined.

Comment: And you're missing the other false string. Wouldn't hurt to mention other false values.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to happen for that string. That could be true for other strings.

```
$results->{'Key_1'} = '';     # Empty string is false.
$results->{'Key_1'} = '0';    # Zero is false.
```

Or maybe you didn't assign a string at all

```
$results->{'Key_1'} = 0;      # Zero is false.
$results->{'Key_1'} = undef;  # Undef is false.
```

[`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined) will return true for the empty string and zero:

```
if ( defined( $results->{'Key_1'} ) ) {
```

[`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists) will return true for the empty string, zero and undef:

```
if ( exists( $results->{'Key_1'} ) ) {
```